# R Script Visual. Forcing Y-Axis values to show as text

Tags: r, ggplot2, rscript

I've got a simple dumbbell chart in R and I would like my y-axis to plot the values as text.  As my y-axis values are numbers by default it's treating them as such but I need them to show as text.   As you can see from my example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bentham7246/ngcmu9r8/2/),  the plot is not quite right.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggalt)


df <- data.frame(trt=c(11111,22222,33333,44444,55555), l=c(20, 40, 10, 30, 50), r=c(70, 50, 30, 60, 80))

ggplot(df, aes(y=trt, x=l, xend=r)) + 
  geom_dumbbell(size=3, color="#e3e2e1", 
                colour_x = "#5b8124", colour_xend = "#bad744",
                dot_guide=TRUE, dot_guide_size=0.25) +
  labs(x=NULL, y=NULL, title="ggplot2 geom_dumbbell with dot guide") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(panel.grid.major.x=element_line(size=0.05)) +
  theme(panel.grid.major.y=element_blank())
```

Answer (score 0):

Think I've sorted this one myself.   Adding "Factor" to the y-axis variable now shows it as a category rather than numeric.

So the top of my ggplot function now reads:    `ggplot(df, aes(y=factor(trt), x=l, xend=r))`

Comment: You could accept your own answer as the accepted answer. This may seem sort of self-congratulatory, but it is actually a convenience for other people when they look for questions that don't have an accepted answer yet.